# Installing "wrong" WhatsApp on Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, installation, tablet

My friend purchased a new tablet, "Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite", to replace their current "Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2016)".

I am trying to help them move WhatsApp over. However, all my installation attempts are installing a weird beta version of WhatsApp that acts like "WhatsApp Web" only.

In other words, instead of asking for a phone number upon first access, it is showing me a QR code and requesting me to go to the other device and link it, just like WhatsApp Web does.

What I want is to make the new tablet the new "main" WhatsApp application, replacing the current tablet. How to do this?

Comment: are you asking about how to install WhatsApp?

Comment: @alecxs How to install it correctly, yes, since the installation from google play is incorrect in this case. Maybe google play is detecting the device incorrectly?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp

Comment: @alecxs Thanks but same problem happens. I suspect your link points to the same place I started from.

Comment: click on [DOWNLOAD APK
49.43 MB](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/whatsapp-inc/whatsapp/whatsapp-2-22-13-77-release/whatsapp-messenger-2-22-13-77-android-apk-download) button (other buttons are adds) and install apk yourself (permissions required)

Answer (score 2):

Whatsapp is linked to the mobile number. If you install it on a non-mobile device, then it can only be a mimic of another device.

That is why it's behaving like a web version. This version has to link to a main device with a sim card / phone number.

You may have to wait a while for the truly windows version, according to this report from [indianexpress](https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/social/why-we-need-whatsapp-web-to-work-without-a-phone-5859987/)

> Facebook-owned WhatsApp is reportedly working on a desktop version of the app that may allow users to use the messaging platform even when the phone is not connected to the internet. The information comes from a reliable leaker WABetaInfo, which claimed that WhatsApp is building a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) that would work even when the phone is off.
>
> For those who don’t know; WhatsApp can be accessed on a computer via WhatsApp Web app for PC or web.whatsapp.com address on a browser. All you need to do is log-in into the WhatsApp Web and you will be able to receive and send messages via PC without the need to touch your phone.
>
> However, in order to use WhatsApp on PC, you need to have WhatsApp installed on your phone and the device must have internet connectivity.

Additionally, Whatsapp can no longer be installed on several phones after Nov 2021.

> Currently, we provide support for and recommend using the following devices:
>
> Android running OS 4.1 and newer
>
> iPhone running iOS 12 and newer
>
> KaiOS 2.5.0 and newer, including JioPhone and JioPhone 2

from [Whatsapp faq](https://faq.whatsapp.com/1150261202542208/?locale=en_US)

On another site, `S3 mini` is listed as one of the devices that it will not work on.  If your tablet has a lower version of android, then try to update it first.

Comment: Thanks! But although it is a tablet, I put a SIM card on it and even tested a standard phone call to my mobile phone which worked perfectly. Therefore, I suspect that Whatsapp is incorrectly assuming that the device is non-mobile. Any ideas with this?

Comment: Is the SIM still in it ?

Comment: I wonder why the Windows version is mentioned here even if the device is Android...?

Answer (score 0):

OP here.

It somehow worked. We uninstalled WhatsApp from the old tablet, and then tried again to install it (normally, from Play Store) on the new tablet and then it just worked. I have no idea how this was possible though, I can't explain it.

<sup>Note: This was done a few days after I posted the question, but I am only adding the answer now because I forgot to do it.</sup>